# this[a] has no properties in ext js

Tags: extjs

I am new to extjs. I have to display a form and and a grid in one page. Grid is showing properly. and the form field are not displaying. In script error it is showing error in ext-all.js. what may be the problem when showing "this[a] has no properties" in firefox script errors? please help me to complete this task.

Comment: Please post some code.  I recently spent 1.5 months doing ExtJS work, and that's what they would tell you on their forum.  You can always post there (http://extjs.com/forum/) but I might be able to help, the ExtJS president has contacted me about working for them

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you refer to an object/widget which is not yet being rendered (But you suppose it to be).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ext-all-debug.js version of Ext to get a better error message. The Ext JS library ships with two files which contain the library (ext-all.js and ext-all-debug.js)

ext-all.js has been run through the YUI Compressor tool and has removed all whitespace, line breaks and comments. YUI compressor will also rename variable names to short versions like "a".

If you use ext-all-debug.js you will receive a better error message.